# Need to convert image url to a Base_64 data url with wordpress function..

Tags: functions, images, shortcode, urls

I need to convert an image url (wordpress avatar) to a base_64 encode data using a wordpress function . I have a shortcode that has the image url for all wordpress users...

For example... [user_meta_avatar_pic] ; which will show an image like below..

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/2010-brown-bear.jpg

I need [user_meta_avatar_pic] shortcode to be converted to a base64_encode data

Base64_encode for image above = aHR0cHM6Ly91cGxvYWQud2lraW1lZGlhLm9yZy93aWtpcGVkaWEvY29tbW9ucy83Lzc5LzIwMTAtYnJvd24tYmVhci5qcGc=

I need this base64_encode url for a services I am using with a SAAS imaging product.

Comment: Do you want to base64 encode the *image* or the *URL*? That looks like the base64 encode of the URL, but I'm not sure what use that is.

Comment: I want to base64 encode the url...  I need to append that url to another service

Comment: What service? I can understand why a service might need the image itself base64 encoded, but I can't understand why the URL itself would need to be encoded.

Comment: It is for a service name Cloudinary... Here is the url I am trying to create.. https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_200,h_200,c_thumb,g_face,r_max,l_fetch:aHR0cHM6Ly9yZXMuY2xvdWRpbmFyeS5jb20vZGVtby9pbWFnZS9mYWNlYm9vay82NTY0NjU3MjI1MS5qcGc=/fl_layer_apply,g_north_east/flower.jpg

Comment: I am trying to add a users avatar to a background pic

Comment: This is where the base64 url need to be attached... l_fetch:aHR0cHM6Ly9yZXMuY2xvdWRpbmFyeS5jb20vZGVtby9pbWFnZS9mYWNlYm9vay82NTY0NjU3MjI1MS5qcGc=

Answer (score 1):

In your post you wrote : "which will show an image like below", I assume that your shortcode return an `img` tag and you have to find your URL here, tell me if I'm wrong.

Using `DOMDocument` http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domdocument.php to parse your `img` tag is a good idea.

```
$img = do_shortcode('[user_meta_avatar_pic]'); // Here your get your img tag

// Use DOMDocument to parse your img tag
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($img);
$img_url = base64_encode($dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src')); // Encode the extracted src from your img tag
```

You can also use **regex**, I have no idea about performances comparison beetween a **regex** and `DOMDocument`.

Comment: The shortcode just shows the url of the image... Not exactly the pic.... It could be used for an image tag like <img src="[user_meta_avatar_pic]" alt="Mountain View">

Comment: Ok ! `base64_decode(do_shortcode('[user_meta_avatar_pic]'));`